# How do I switch user without any references to the old one?

Tags: sudo, su

A while back, when playing with unprivileged LXC, I discovered that the command to create a container failed if I used `su` to switch to the user, but it worked if I used `ssh user@localhost` to login.

This is not a LXC related question, but it made me wonder how to best switch user without leaving references or bringing variables from the old one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A difference between `su` and `ssh` is that the latter actually involves a login shell, whereas the former does not by default -- although it does create a new interactive shell (see INVOCATION at the top of `man bash` for the significance of *interactive* and *login* shells).  From `man su`:

> For  backward compatibility su defaults to not change the current
>   directory and to only set the environment variables HOME and SHELL (plus USER and LOGNAME if the target user is not root).  It is  recommended to always **use the --login option** (instead of its shortcut -) to avoid side effects caused by
>   mixing environments.

So, you could try `su --login` and see if that does what you want.

I'm presuming you're using a GUI, which is why you don't simply exit and log in again.  However, that *may* be possible anyway (depending, I believe, on your init system), by simply running `login` from whatever terminal you are using.  If it works, you should see the normal `login:` prompt, and when done you can `exit` from that as per `su`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - but `su --login` didn't solve this issue.

Comment: Just in case there was any confusion, the `login` command mentioned in the last paragraph is distinct from `su --login`, so if you haven't tried that do (but again: `login` may not work at all this way on some systems).  You may want to clarify the nature of your problem in the question since "bringing references" is very ambiguous and if `su --login` doesn't help then you may have an **[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).**